# Using NSURLConnection Multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsrunloop, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am trying to start a second NSURLConnection after starting the first one. My first one works perfectly: the appropriate delegates are all called, and everything executes as planned. However, after the first one finishes, I create a second one, and nothing happens (the delegate is never called). What could be happening? I know I can't reuse the same NSURLConnection, but I reinitialise it before using it again, so it should be a completely new connection.

Here's my code for starting (both) connections. It's the same instance variable, but it's reinitialised. Also note that the second one is not started until the first one has finished running completely.

```
if (connection) {
    [connection cancel];
}

currentResponse = nil;
error = nil;

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
if (!connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be initialized.");
    [self connectionFinished];
} else {
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}
```

Comment: IS the connection created at all? Do you get the "Connection could not be initialized." message being logged? Is the method where this code resides called?

Comment: This code is being called, and the connection is initialised both times. The initialisation failed message is never logged.

Comment: are you always on the main thread?

Comment: No I'm on a different thread (the same thread both times).

Comment: hmn, I've never seen delegates get called if the request was on a background thread.

Comment: Did you implement didFailWithError:?

Comment: I did; that is never getting called.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it worked repeatedly for me. You've logged the various delegate methods, and none gets called?

Comment: Delegates get called the first time (didReceiveData, didReceiveResponse, willSendRequest, connectionDidFinishLoading), but not the second time.

Comment: Well, that's a puzzle. After [connection start], try logging connection.delegate to make sure that didn't go away somehow. Seems unlikely, but I'm grasping at straws here.

Comment: After a lot of hunting, I tried something and suspect it has something to do with the run loop being started/stopped.

Comment: Are you stopping the currentRunLoop?

Comment: You say you aren't on the main thread, but you don't say what sort of thread you are on. (This is like pulling teeth!)  My guess is that either you don't have a run loop, or that your NSOperation is ending, or your GCD task is completing, before the second NSConnection gets a chance to do its callback.

Comment: I suspect that using `setDelegateQueue` (if you're using operation queues) will solve your problem, but I have a secondary observation: If you have to run your two network operations consecutively, you can, but it's worth noting that if they can be run concurrently, you'll see a noticeable performance improvement. Clearly if one is dependent upon the next, you wouldn't do that, but if there is no such dependency, it's worth doing the little extra work to allow concurrent network operations. Clearly, this is secondary to your current issue, but it's something to consider as you move forward.

Comment: @MarkBernstein I am running an NSOperation, so I suspect you're right: my NSOperation is ending before the second NSConnection gets a chance to do its callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared how you're running it "on a different thread", but the typical problem is if you are using dispatch queues or operation queues, your connection is running asynchronously, itself, and therefore the dispatched operation is completing and getting released and you're losing your connection.

A couple of possible solutions:

1. You can perform your network operations synchronously in this background operation of yours (this is the only time you should do synchronous network operations). This is the simplest solution, though you haven't explained what you're doing with your `NSURLConnection`, so this technique may or may not work for you. But if you're just trying to download something from a URL, you can do:

   ```
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                        options:0
                                          error:&error];
   ```

   This approach doesn't work if you're doing any a little more complicated that requires the [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods, such challenge-response authentication or if you are streaming using `didReceiveData` to reduce your app's memory footprint or for performances reasons, etc. But if you're just trying to download data from a remote server (e.g. retrieving an image, an XML/JSON feed, etc.), this is easiest.
2. In a similar vein (i.e. you don't need the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods), but you're you're creating some rich `NSURLRequest` for your connection, then you can use either [`sendAsynchronousRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10) or [`sendSynchronousRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI).
3. If you need the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` calls, you can use the [`setDelegateQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW3) (designating a `NSOperationQueue`) or [`scheduleInRunLoop`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW2) (designating a `NSRunLoop`), and it will automatically dispatch the connection updates to the appropriate queue/runloop. Just make sure to `initWithRequest` using the `startImmediately` option of `NO`, set the delegate queue or runloop, and then `start` the connection. With this technique, you preserve the full richness of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` if you absolutely need it.
4. Alternatively, if you're not using operation queues, you could also keep your background operation alive until the connection is done. This approach gives you synchronous behavior in you background operation (keeping your connection alive), while preserving the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. This technique is demonstrated by [Apple's XMLPerformance Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html) (see the `downloadAndParse` method of CocoaXMLParser.m and LibXMLParser.m), where they initiate the `NSURLConnection` and then use the following construct to keep the background operation alive until the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods end up setting the `done` instance variable:

   ```
   do {
       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
                                beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
   } while (!done);
   ```

I confess that I find this final approach vaguely dissatisfying and would lean towards the other alternatives, depending upon what flexibility and functionality you need from your `NSURLConnection`. For us to provide more meaningful counsel, you just need to provide more information about (a) the sort of work you're doing in your `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods; and (b) which technology you're using to run your code in the background.

For a few more options, also feel free to see [GCD and async NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918501/gcd-and-async-nsurlconnection).

Comment: Wow, what a thorough answer! I appreciate the effort you put into that. It turned out I just needed to make sure I didn't finish the NSOperation before I had finished with all my NSConnections. I definitely wanted to run them synchronously, as one depended on the one before, and I needed the ability to handle redirects. Still, this is a very helpful reference for me.